# Is my method of finding XSS vulnerability's a good place to start?

Tags: php, mysql, xss

**Information**

This is a quick question regarding finding possible XSS attacks in my website.

I am currently securing my website and have learnt that a good way to prevent XSS is to use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` to make sure that the html is displayed rather than ran.

**My solution**

I have pumped my database with test data which is exactly as below `<script>console.log("This Page is Vulnerable");</script>`

Therefore any page that displays any row of data that isnt escaped will put out a console.log which will then allow me to hunt it down in my source and escape it.

**Question**

Now I understand this isn't the only thing I would have to do to prevent XSS, but does this at least narrow the possibility of persistent XSS attacks?

Lastly, does anyone have any advice on where to go from here? (I understand this is a vague question, so please ignore if you like. Otherwise, any questions will be answered ASAP.)

Thank you.

Comment: Start from testing all of your inputs by yourself as a potential hacker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ofcourse, a single function wrapping the input/output data is never enough. Programming ain't no magic, it's logic.

Assuming you have this example HTML/JS/PHP for some reason:

```
<form action="" method="POST" />
<input type="text" name="yourInput" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script><?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['yourInput'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></script>
```

For some reason, which maybe nobody can explain, you put the user input into `<script>` tags. You have used HTML Special Chars, so no quotes or `<`, `>` will be present, but let's say the user enter this:

`alert(document.cookie)`

there's no quotes and opening tags, but still after submitting the form, on the next load an ALERT with the current user cookie will be displayed.

So, as I said in my comments, you should go through all your inputs and test their behavior. Try to think as a potential hacker.

It's not all about using a function which is wrapping the data, but where the data is used. If you put it in the wrong place, no function will save you. In the example above, you need to place data in the right place, and if you are going to use it - use it as a string.

Comment: I see, Thank you for your detailed comment. Regarding your answer I find it hard to think like a hacker as I am not one. But I am trying to learn what is possible and how to prevent it the best I can. Lastly, is sanitising more a case of white-listing what you are expecting or black listing what you do not?

Comment: Depends. In most of the cases you expect only one thing and don't want the other thousands-and-more-variations to be present. For example if you are expecting integer to be typed in the input, you don't need to test with `htmlspecialchars()` to test `if(is_string($_POST['input']))` and other possibilities, but just cast the input to int with like `(int)` or `intval($_POST['input'])`.

Comment: Ah, I see! Going back to your answer again... I do not output any user inputted code to inside a script tag. Its all field inputs etc, would `htmlspecialchars` be sufficient in that example (for preventing XSS)? If not could you (please) post an example of something that could get around it. (Or PM, whatever you like).

Comment: If you are just printing the input i.e. in <div>'s and <p>'s or smth like that, in most of the cases it could be enough. But I still suggest to cast to what you expect, and to escape what you really don't need

Comment: Yeah, exactly that. For example a users profile page displays their f_name, l_name, username in html elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is exactly what you say — "a good start" — insofar as it should catch any simple mistakes where you simply meant to escape the user input but forgot.

In fact, I'd be inclined to simplify it further, and just try injecting an arbitrary string that *should* get escaped, like, say "`<<<<<`", and searching the *HTML source* of the returned page for that string to see if it appears unescaped anywhere.  (Don't forget to also test it with single and double quotes, since those need to be escaped too in attributes.)  This kind of testing would even be fairly simple to automate.

What neither of those methods will catch is cases where you've *tried* to escape or sanitize the input, but have done it poorly, so that the simple test inputs won't pass, but other vulnerabilities still remain.  However, if you can be confident that you haven't done that, then these simple tests should be enough.

Anyway, where you IMO should go from here is getting in the habit of writing your code such that XSS vulnerabilities can't even happen.  In particular, get used to:

1. Escaping *every* string that isn't *supposed* to be HTML with `htmlspecialchars()` before embedding it in HTML.  (Of course, the same goes, *mutatis mutandis*, for embedding anything that isn't supposed to be SQL into SQL code, or anything that isn't supposed to be JavaScript into JavaScript code, etc.)

   This is IMO best done *just* before the string is printed or concatenated with HTML, so that you never have to worry about whether or not the string has already been escaped earlier.  (Tip: if you're tired of typing `htmlspecialchars()` all the time, consider defining your own, shorter alias for it.)
2. Thinking about user inputs (or anything else potentially coming from unknown sources) not in terms of what they're *supposed* to contain, or even what an attacker *might* inject into them, but simply in terms of what they *could* possibly contain.

   That is, if your code takes a string as an input, write it so that it behaves correctly even if given *any* string of *any* length containing *any* arbitrary bytes in any order.

   Conversely, if you cannot be sure that some code will do that (e.g. because you didn't write it), explicitly verify and/or force any inputs you pass into it to only have values that you *know* it can handle.

Comment: Thanks for your information, although some of it I do not understand I will defiantly be researching after I post this comment. In reply to your suggestion about using `<<<<<`, that is the same method I am doing with the console.log, meaning if I see a log ill open up the source and CTRL+F for script tags that shouldn't be there. Also at your answer #1; I have made a simple function called `basic_escape($string);` that does just that. (Sorry if this message seems abit messy, I am finding it hard to format a comment so it is easily read.)